# Word/slang for "I have just committed the source code, please update your working copy"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I usually send this message over SMS to my coworkers, well, very frequently. I think maybe there is a slang term that I can use so I can type less.

Comment: IHJCTSC, PUYWC.

Comment: Committed to SVN, pls sync.

Comment: Slang is not a count noun.  You cannot say “a slang”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone who is interested in your changes will know that they have to update their working copy so you can leave out the second part of your sentence. "I've committed my code" or "I've committed my changes" is probably enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well they're not slang — synchronize your project, synchronize with repository.